# Extracting data from one Excel sheet to another, with no spaces in rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I've got an Excel workbook with 3 sheets.  One is MasterList.  One is Assigned. One is Contacted.

In the MasterList, there's a dropdown next to a name.  In that dropdown is "assigned" or "contacted." If someone selects "assigned", I need it to display itself in the "Assigned" sheet and vice versa for if they select "contacted" from the dropdown.  This would normally be easy for me.  I'd just fill the rows in "Contacted" up with a formula like so:

```
IF(MasterList!D2="contacted", MasterList!C2, "")
```

However, this leaves my Contacted sheet full of holes where there might be a name on C2, but not again until C10.

How can I have the names pulled over to the Contacted sheet, but go into the next available row, so that even if they're spaced out on the MasterList, they'll be bunched up at the top of the Contacted sheet with no spaces between the names?

Answer (score 0):

You can update the formula you offered as such. Since, it is an array formula **Control + Shift + Enter** is pressed in the end and it needs to be copied to the cells below

```
=IF(MasterList!D$2="contacted",IFERROR(INDEX(MasterList!$C$2:$C$100,SMALL(IF(ISTEXT(MasterList!$C$2:$C$100),ROW($A$1:$A$99),""),ROW(D1))),""),"")
```

The formula assumes the list in MasterList sheet is in the range C2:C100. It can be changed for longer lists and `ROW($A$1:$A$99)` can contain any range as long as the number of rows is equal to the number of rows in the names list of MasterList sheet. `ROW(D1)` can point to any cell.

Here is the link to the file. 
[worksheet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BOdYUaJ1QjywYDa6mon7DB1aZx061-7A/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Unfortunately, all that does is add a #ref error and try to open a file, oddly enough. Hmm.

Comment: Let me check. I am using a non-English version, may be some problems during translation. I will share a file if needed.

Comment: Added a file. Hope this helps.